# Create an auhtentication popUp

Tags: robotframework

With Robot Framework I automatizate a connexion to a website.
To do this, I used Dialogs Library to ask for a username and a password with the command "Get Value From User". The thing is, the library let the user enter only one by one value (a first popup where robot ask Username then a second where it ask the password). Dialogs Library do not support to ask several values in the same popup or window. But is there a way to do it ? (I do not find anything, and I almost never learn python to creat my own library (it is in my plan to do it asap)).   Thank you for help !

Answer (score 0):

Possible, yes. If you need to ask, not easy.

Dialogs uses tkinter toolkit, when you call a keyword from dialogs keyword library, library will create a temporary gui element and runs the event loop until its either dismissed or value is provided.

You can make similar keyword that creates tkinter dialog with multiple ui elements, process the event loop until user has indicated that all is fine, exit the event loop and return the field values to the caller.

Comment: I do not know Tkinter... I will try to inform myself about it, thank you !

Comment: code for Dialogs keywords is here: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/libraries/Dialogs.py and standard dialog code (non keyword parts) here: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/libraries/dialogs_py.py  ..  using those as basis could get you further.

Comment: Thank you for your help I will check this !